# Django not adding a string to models

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, model

I am having a problem after I restarted my project from scratch
I can add a value manually to my django model, but when it comes from a variable the user entered, it only pass a blank string..

Some pictures of the logs to be more explicit:
[image]
[image]

**Process:**
So, I am having a simple model Tech and I have a page where you can add a new name to Tech model.
I enter the name (here i entered the name ede dede), click add, then i send it to the backend using AJAX.

In the shell in VSCODE  I see I received the element, but when I add it to my django model Tech, and then print the new object in Tech, it has an ID, everything, but the name is a blank string ""

Moreover, When i print it in my python code, it doesnt even give me the queryset, i have nothing.

How come?

Here is a piece of my code

**VIEWS.PY:**

```
@ajax_required
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def AddNewEmployee(request):
    newtechname = request.POST.get('new_employee').title()    
    response_data = {}
    print('new employee: '+newtechname)
    print(type(newtechname))

    if Tech.objects.filter(name=newtechname).exists():
        response_data['success'] = False
        response_data['result'] = 'This name already exists'
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        techname = Tech(name=newtechname)
        techname = Tech(selected=True) #add new tech to model
        techname.save() #save new name to model

        response_data['success'] = True
        response_data['result'] = 'Added a new teammate successfully!'
        response_data['tech_id'] = techname.id #get new name id from model
        response_data['tech_name'] = techname.name
        response_data['tech_selected'] = techname.selected
        print(techname)
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Tech(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**JS:**

```
$('#add-employee').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.target.getAttribute('id')==('add-employee')){
            console.log('form submitted!'); //sanity check
            AddNewEmployee();   
        }
    });
function AddNewEmployee(){
    console.log('AddNewEmployee is working!');
    console.log($('#addtech_id').val()); //get the input value from input id 

    const addemployee_form_url = $('#add-employee').attr('action'); //get the form url
    new_employee = $('#addtech_id').val(); // data sent with the post request
    console.log(typeof new_employee);
    let request_data = {
        'new_employee': new_employee,
        'csrf_token':csrftoken
    }
    $self = $(this)

    $.ajax({
        url : addemployee_form_url, //endpoint
        type : "POST", //httpmethod
        data : request_data,

        //handle a successful response
        success : function(response){
            $('#addtech_id').val(''); //remove the value from the input
            console.log(response); // log the returned json to the console
            console.log("A connexion to the backend has been established with success!"); // sanity check

            //Add to selected list
            if (response['success']){
                AddToSelectedList(response['tech_id'], response['tech_name']);
                $('#results').html("<h5><div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert style='color:green;'>"+response['result']+"</div><h5>");
            }
            else{
                $('#results').html("<h5><div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert style='color:red;'>This name is already in the list!</div><h5>");
            }
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });


}
```

What I dont understand is, why is it printing (in views.py) newtechname correctly, which i can even see its type is a string so no problem, then, it passes an empty string to Tech model when techname = Tech(name=newtechname)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how about you create the the object using Tech.objects.create() ?

Comment: Hi Walid, thanks for answering. If im not wrong, create() method is the same than instanciating and then save, isnt it? Anyway, Im going to try it in few hours and get back to you ASAP. Thanks

Comment: yeah just for troubleshooting pupose

Comment: so did you try that ?

Comment: i just tried.... it worked ! thousand thanks!!!!!

Comment: so i think its because the new object was not instanciated. thanks!

Comment: I will add the response so it can be used for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
else:
        techname = Tech(name=newtechname)
        techname = Tech(selected=True) #add new tech to model
        techname.save() #save new name to model
```

You are trying to create an object that does not exist as Tech(name=newtechname) doesn't create the object, you can use that after using Tech.objects.create()

So in your case changing that with the traditional objects.create() has resolved the issue.

Comment: well, thanks again for the explanation. I got it ! hope it will help others too. Cheers

Comment: Strange thing is that it worked before? then i restarted my project from scratch and it stopped working.. Anyway it works now